# Vue JS timepicker SUM Hours dan Minutes Calculation

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem when calculating the total from the timepicker on the repeater field.
I created a function on vue js computed.

Here's the script:
https://jsfiddle.net/andreasdan/afwy6k9n/42/

[image]

This ini my calculation script:

```
computed: {
        totalDuration: function() {
          let total = 0;
          this.detail_data.map( item => {
            total += item.hour_timespan
          })
          return total;
        }
      },
```

The data I want to display is like this:
Total Duration : 23:30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Hi @Toni Rhubanaga,

You can modify your `computed` property like this.

First, you can loop through the `detail_data array` and add up the `hour_timespan` values, which you are already have done. Then, you could convert the total number of minutes into hours and minutes by dividing the total number of minutes by `60`, I guess. Then, use `toString()` for in a string in the format `HH:MM`.

```js
computed: {
  totalDuration: function() {
    let totalMinutes = 0;
    this.detail_data.map( item => {
      totalMinutes += item.hour_timespan
    })

    let hours = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60);
    let minutes = totalMinutes % 60;

    return hours.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  }
},
```

Well, it converts the total number of minutes into hours and minutes, and then format the result as a string in the format. Total duration in the format `HH:MM`, Right.
And display the total duration in your HTML, like this.

`<div>Total Duration: {{ totalDuration }}</div>`